# How to deal with single-line comment when using pg_hint_plan

Tags: postgresql, metabase, pg-hint-plan

I'm trying to test some query plans using `pg_hint_plan` through Metabase, which under the hood prefixes the query with a single-line comment, so that the query actually run is something like:

```
-- Metabase:: userID: 123 queryType: native queryHash: 4567890
explain analyze
/*+ SeqScan(users) */
select id from users where email = 'test@me'
```

Now, the [docs](https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_hint_plan/blob/master/docs/hint_details.md#syntax-and-placement) say: "`pg_hint_plan` reads hints from only the first block comment", implying this should work, but I find that the `--` comment prevents `pg_hint_plan` from doing its thing.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: I'd report that as a bug to the maintainers.  In your report, it would be better not to have the statement start with the comment, as many client (including psql) strip out such comments. So something like `explain -- comment here \n analyze ....`